# JBoss war deployment

Tags: java, jboss, war

Apologies for having the classes masked.

A tricky scenario.

This war deploys ok when it is a part of an ear. But when I try to deploy it as a separate deployable entity, it flashes this message. It has all the dependencies it requires in 'provided' scope. I am not sure if JBoss class loader does a lookup in a different location other than that of the one which is looked up when the ear is loaded.

```
2015-01-20 17:50:35,485 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-13) WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from com.xxxx.yyy.services.dddd.zzzz.eeee.LoadedClass because of underlying class loading error
2015-01-20 17:50:35,485 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading] (MSC service thread 1-13) catching: org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error while loading class com.xxxx.yyy.services.dddd.zzzz.eeee.LoadedClass
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:176) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadWeldClass(BeanDeployer.java:116) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:79) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:135) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:349) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63) [jboss-as-weld-7.3.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/xxxx/yyy/services/dddd/zzzz/eeee/MyClass
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$8.work(SecureReflections.java:175) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$8.work(SecureReflections.java:172) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAndWrap(SecureReflectionAccess.java:63) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.getDeclaredMethods(SecureReflections.java:172) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:240) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:126) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.load(ClassTransformer.java:60) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.load(ClassTransformer.java:51) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:71) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:112) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:93) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:164) [weld-core-1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1.jar:1.1.17.SP3-redhat-1]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xxxx.yyy.services.dddd.zzzz.eeee.MyClassfrom [Module "deployment.blah-server-war-1.0.23-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 34 more
```

Any Help appreciated.

War content looks like the below.

Blahblah.War
   |
   ---META-INF
   |
   ---WEB-INF----
   |                                               |
   ---index.htm    |_____classes
                        |_____lib
                        |_____beans.xml
                        |_____faces-config.xml
                        |_____web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error doesn't happen when you deploy it inside an ear, then probably the lib folder of your ear is providing the missing class.

I recommend comparing the jars contained in the lib folder of your ear against the one's in your war's lib.

Maybe you have another app bundled in the ear which uses the missing jar, so it gets copied in the lib folder of your ear and makes your war deploy.